# Uploading Large File in C# & ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to upload a file using C# and ASP.NET MVC, and I am getting this error:

> HTTP Error 413.1 - Request Entity Too Large
> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length.

This is how I configure my `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"  executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="104857600" enable="true"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: first hit did you try https://forums.asp.net/t/2160766.aspx?HTTP+Error+413+1+Request+Entity+Too+Large+The+page+was+not+displayed+because+the+request+entity+is+too+large+

Answer (score 1):

```html
For IIS7 and above, you also need to add the lines below:
 <system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```